# transactional email not getting delivered to some email extensions

Tags: magento, email, transactional

I am using magento 1.3.2.4

My problem with transactional email is that the email sent from magento does not get delivered to some extensions like email@somedomain.net or .gov or .edu It works for .com domains or gmail

I have transactional email set for the invoice which is sent.

I am wondering how to go about this and resolve this issue.
app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Email\Template.php

The function here $text = $this->getProcessedTemplate($variables, true); brings the text string for the body of the email. If I assign $text with some html it works. So probably older version of magento is not generating the html properly.

Any ideas to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the proper headers? Some domains have stricter filters, so you are probably getting bounced for not passing.

Comment: I already tested the headers. If i replace the content of the variable mentioned above it works. $text when assigned some other html fixes it. It does not even appear in spam. Interestingly the email I receive in gmail is not delivered when forwarding to this address which again confirms its problematic html content in the body. Now the problem is how to upgrade this function of old magento. Other newer magento version work problem free again pointing towards problematic body text.

Comment: Sorry - missed that part of your question. Assuming the intended output is clean text/html, and your params are correct, it sounds like an issue with Magento itself. You might have more luck with their customer service...

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this by editing the cms content of the transactional email. had to remove the white spaces and then it started working. 
upgrading zend email code is another tougher option I thought.